QTextBrowser.append не передает все параметры html
QTextBrowser, добавляю в него строки через append.
Выходит примерно такой код с моей стороны:
self.QTB.append('<p style="font-size:12pt; color:#ff0000;">Какой то текст</p>')
print(self.QTB.toHtml())

Однако, в .toHtml распечатается, что он перевел мой p в span, и, к примеру, если у меня стоит font-size:0pt то я вообще в .toHtmlе не увижу font-size как такового.
Как то можно сообщать QTextBrowserу и обратно полное содержимое? Без всяких измышлений, что мол если сайз=0 то сайз вообще не нужен?
Вот пример:
import sys
from PyQt5.Qt import *


class MainWindow(QMainWindow):
    def __init__(self):
        super().__init__()
        self.centralWidget = QWidget()
        self.setCentralWidget(self.centralWidget)

        self.textBrowser = QTextBrowser()

        self.layout = QGridLayout(self.centralWidget)
        self.layout.addWidget(self.textBrowser)

        # добавляю строку с разным интересным в текстовое поле
        self.textBrowser.insertHtml(f'<p class="tech" style="visibility:hidden; font-size:8pt; color:#0000ff;">'
                                    f'Вот это должен быть скрытый текст</p><br>')

        # и тут же вывожу - а что же в это самое текстовое поле попало
        print(self.textBrowser.toHtml())


if __name__ == '__main__':
    app = QApplication(sys.argv)
    app.setFont(QFont("Times", 12, QFont.Bold))
    w = MainWindow()
    w.resize(700, 300)
    w.show()
    sys.exit(app.exec())

И то что мне в консоль вывел print - а где class? А где visibility?:
<!DOCTYPE HTML PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD HTML 4.0//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/REC-html40/strict.dtd">
<html><head><meta name="qrichtext" content="1" /><style type="text/css">
p, li { white-space: pre-wrap; }
</style></head><body style=" font-family:'Times'; font-size:12pt; font-weight:600; font-style:normal;">
<p style=" margin-top:12px; margin-bottom:12px; margin-left:0px; margin-right:0px; -qt-block-indent:0; text-indent:0px;"><span style=" font-size:8pt; color:#0000ff;">Вот это должен быть скрытый текст</span></p>
<p style=" margin-top:0px; margin-bottom:0px; margin-left:0px; margin-right:0px; -qt-block-indent:0; text-indent:0px;"><br /></p></body></html>


Gh0sTG0, пожалуйста, предоставьте [mcve], который демонстрирует проблему и лучше расскажите что вы хотите сделать.

@S.Nick что я хочу сделать - тут https://ru.stackoverflow.com/posts/1578025 , просто наткнулся на момент более общего вида, который может вылезти не только при том что делаю я конкретно.

@S.Nick добавил пример

При управление форматированным текстом Qt, один из важных аспектов, 
который следует учитывать, использования текстовых виджетов,
которые предоставляют такие функции, как setHtml(), toHtml() и insertHtml(),  
то, что все это достигается
с помощью небольшого подмножества HTML, 
которое обеспечивает часть функций таблиц стилей,
совместимых с реализацией CSS 2.1
На ваш вопрос: "А где visibility?",
ответ: "данное CSS-свойство не поддерживаемые обработчиком форматированного текста Qt".
